# Is low latency mode safe to use with Linux serial ports?

Tags: linux-device-driver, tty, powerpc

Is it safe to use the low_latency tty mode with Linux serial ports? The [tty_flip_buffer_push](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/tty/tty_buffer.c#L512) function is documented that it "must not be called from IRQ context if port->low_latency is set." Nevertheless, many low-level serial port drivers call it from an ISR whether or not the flag is set. For example, the [mpc52xx driver calls flip buffer](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/tty/serial/mpc52xx_uart.c#L1002) unconditionally after each read from its FIFO.

A consequence of the low latency flip buffer in the ISR is that the line discipline driver is entered within the IRQ context. My goal is to get latency of one millisecond or less, reading from a high speed mpc52xx serial port. Setting low_latency acheives the latency goal, but it also violates the documented precondition for tty_flip_buffer_push.

Comment: I was using kernel 2.6.28, which is quite old. The low_latency flag is unnecessary with newer kernels. The driver has stopped using delayed_work when transferring data from the low level driver to the line discipline driver. https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/f23eb2b2b28547fc70df82dd5049eb39bec5ba12

Comment: Although is seems unnecessary, the low_latency flag is still present in the latest Linux kernel. It still looks dangerous to use with many low level drivers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question was asked on [linux-serial on Fri, 19 Aug 2011](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.linux.serial/5797/focus=5803).

No, low latency is not safe in general.

However, in the particular case of 3.10.5 `low_latency` is safe.

The comments above `tty_flip_buffer_push` read:

> "This function must not be called from IRQ context if port->low_latency is set."

However, the code (3.10.5, drivers/tty/tty_buffer.c) contradicts this:

```
void tty_flip_buffer_push(struct tty_port *port)
{
    struct tty_bufhead *buf = &port->buf;
    unsigned long flags;

    spin_lock_irqsave(&buf->lock, flags);
    if (buf->tail != NULL)
            buf->tail->commit = buf->tail->used;
    spin_unlock_irqrestore(&buf->lock, flags);

    if (port->low_latency)
            flush_to_ldisc(&buf->work);
    else
            schedule_work(&buf->work);
}
EXPORT_SYMBOL(tty_flip_buffer_push);
```

The use of `spin_lock_irqsave`/`spin_unlock_irqrestore` makes this code safe to call from interrupt context.

There is a test for `low_latency` and if it is set, `flush_to_ldisc` is called directly. This flushes the flip buffer to the line discipline immediately, at the cost of making the interrupt processing longer. The `flush_to_ldisc` routine is also coded to be safe for use in interrupt context. I guess that an earlier version was unsafe.

If `low_latency` is *not* set, then `schedule_work` is called. Calling `schedule_work` is the classic way to invoke the "bottom half" handler from the "top half" in interrupt context. This causes `flush_to_ldisc` to be called from the "bottom half" handler at the next clock tick.

Looking a little deeper, both the comment and the test seem to be in Alan Cox's original `e0495736` commit of `tty_buffer.c`. This commit was a re-write of earlier code, so it seems that at one time there wasn't a test. Whoever added the test and fixed `flush_to_ldisc` to be interrupt-safe did not bother to fix the comment.

So, always believe the code, not the comments.

*However*, in the same code in 3.12-rc* (as of October 23, 2013) it looks like the problem was opened again when the spin_lock_irqsave's in flush_to_ldisc were removed and mutex_locks were added. That is, setting UPF_LOW_LATENCY in the serial_struct flags and calling the TIOCSSERIAL ioctl will again cause "scheduling while atomic".

The latest update from the maintainer is:

```
On 10/19/2013 07:16 PM, Jonathan Ben Avraham wrote:
> Hi Peter,
> "tty_flip_buffer_push" is called from IRQ handlers in most drivers/tty/serial UART drivers.
> 
> "tty_flip_buffer_push" calls "flush_to_ldisc" if low_latency is set.
> "flush_to_ldisc" calls "mutex_lock" in 3.12-rc5, which cannot be used in interrupt context.
> 
> Does this mean that setting "low_latency" cannot be used safely in 3.12-rc5?

Yes, I broke low_latency.

Part of the problem is that the 3.11- use of low_latency was unsafe; too many shared
data areas were simply accessed without appropriate safeguards.

I'm working on fixing it but probably won't make it for 3.12 final.

Regards,
Peter Hurley
```

So, it looks like you should not depend on `low_latency` unless you are sure that you are never going to change your kernel from a version that supports it.

---

**Update: February 18, 2014, kernel 3.13.2**

Stanislaw Gruszka wrote:

```
Hi,

setserial has low_latency option which should minimize receive latency
(scheduler delay). AFAICT it is used if someone talk to external device
via RS-485/RS-232 and need to have quick requests and responses . On
kernel this feature was implemented by direct tty processing from
interrupt context:

void tty_flip_buffer_push(struct tty_port *port)
{
    struct tty_bufhead *buf = &port->buf;

    buf->tail->commit = buf->tail->used;

    if (port->low_latency)
            flush_to_ldisc(&buf->work);
    else
            schedule_work(&buf->work);
} 

But after 3.12 tty locking changes, calling flush_to_ldisc() from
interrupt context is a bug (we got scheduling while atomic bug report
here: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1065087 )

I'm not sure how this should be solved. After Peter get rid all of those
race condition in tty layer, we probably don't want go back to use
spin_lock's there. Maybe we can create WQ_HIGHPRI workqueue and schedule
flush_to_ldisc() work there. Or perhaps users that need to low latency,
should switch to thread irq and prioritize serial irq to meat
retirements. Anyway setserial low_latency is now broken and all who use
this feature in the past can not do this any longer on 3.12+ kernels.

Thoughts ?

Stanislaw
```

Answer (score 2):

A patch has been posted to LKML to address the problem.  It removes the generic code for handling low_latency but keeps the parameter for the low-level drivers to use.

http://www.kernelhub.org/?p=2&msg=419071

I tried forcing low_latency on Linux 3.12 with serial console.  The kernel was very unstable.  If preemption was enabled, it would hang after a few minutes of use.

So the answer for now is to stay away.